# double integral over a convex polygon in C++

Tags: c++, integration, polygon

I want to integrate an arbitrary function, over a given convex polygon. In other world if P is the convex polygon, I want to compute the following integral:

\int \int_P f(x,y) dP

I'd rather to have a library in C++.

Please note that, all the libraries that I have seen so far, including GSL, ROOT, CUBA, are only capable of doing integration over a hyper-cube.

Comment: You could use [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) to convert the double integral into a contour integral - which might be more manageable.

Comment: I searched and could not find a library.  You might have to write it yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: I would divide the polygon into triangles with a Delaunay triangulation and then integrate over the triangles. But in C++...